# How to import data into Hive warehouse from SQL Server 2014 (Unicode) for specific schema

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, cloudera, sqoop

I want to import data from SQL Server and query it from hive.

I created a VirtualBox using cloudera template and also started reading its tutorial.

I am successfully able to import data from SQL Server using sqoop as avro files and then create table in hive and import data from avro file. Then query it from hive.

But import-all-tables command of sqoop only imports table of schema "dbo".
What if I want to import tables with a schema `dw` also? I tried to use import command to import specific table exist in `dw` schema. but that also doesn't work.

Any idea how to import data from SQL Sever using sqoop for non `dbo.` schema related tables as avro? Or import data from SQL Server for other than `dbo.` schema and load it directly into hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Download JDBC driver and copy it to sqoop directory**

```
$ curl -L 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/A/02AAE597-3865-456C-AE7F-613F99F850A8/sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu.tar.gz' | tar xz
$ sudo cp sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar /var/lib/sqoop/
```

**Import table from Sql Server using sqoop**

```
sqoop import --driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" --connect="jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver;database=databasename;username=username;password=passwordofuserprovidedinusername" --username=username --password= passwordofuserprovidedinusername --table="schemaname.tablename" --split-by=primarykeyoftable --compression-codec=snappy --as-avrodatafile --warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse/tablename
```

**Verify if table imported properly**

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
ls -l *.avsc
```

**create new directory  and provide appropriate permissions**

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/examples
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod +rw /user/examples
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ~/*.avsc /user/examples
```

**start hive**

```
hive
```

**import table schema and data from sqoop to hive warehouse**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/tablename’
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/examples/sqoop_import_schemaname_tablename.avsc');
```

**Note:** *make sure while typing command the single quote may change if you are coping the command. There should not be any space in path or filenames.*

Comment: in `avro.schema.url`, why there's a *quickstart.cloudera* prefix? Is it a typo?